# How can I permanently remove/delete a line in route with CentOS 6

Tags: centos, linux-networking, route, deleting

```
root@new [~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
178.18.23.200   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
178.18.23.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
176.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         248.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         178.18.23.253   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I can remove the 176.0.0.0 entry with

```
route delete -net 176.0.0.0/5
```

This works, but after reboot this line comes back. Any idea how to permanently have it removed?

Comment: You need to find where it's coming from.  Can you edit into your question the output of `grep 176 /etc/sysconfig/static-routes /etc/sysconfig/network /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/* /etc/rc.d/rc.local`?

Answer (score 6):

Check /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0,

Grep recursivly for 176.0.0.0 in /etc for the file containing the route

# grep -r "176.0.0.0" /etc

Comment: That was the trick for me. It turned out another app (openVPN) was incorrectly configured to add a static route that broke traffic to the remote network. Thanks!