# How can I permanently remove a line in route with Debian-based distributions?

Tags: debian, linux-networking, route, deleting

```
Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
    default         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
    192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
    192.168.43.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

I can remove the 192.168.1.1 entry with:

```
 ip route del default via 192.168.1.1
```

This works, but after reboot this line comes back. Any idea how to permanently have it removed with Debian-based distributions?

Comment: open file /etc/network/interfaces and remove route

Comment: @stambata I doubt that inside this file he'll find a `route` directive. @OP See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/535622/how-can-i-permanently-remove-delete-a-line-in-route-with-centos-6?rq=1) as well. I guess you're using `DHCP`, right? If so, most probably your router is assigning you a default gateway as well. If that's the case, use a static configuration.

Answer (score 3):

It seems a DHCP server give you this GW on ETH0.

edit this file : `/etc/network/interfaces`

**gf_ way** : use a static configuration for eth0 like :

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.x
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

**stambata way :** use a post-up directive to remove this route

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
post-up route del default gw 192.168.1.1
```